# I want to warn the compiler about possible nulls from external code

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

In the below, C# is confident that 'property' will never be null, but I KNOW that it can be, because the external library is not produced with C#8/nullable types:

```
#nullable enable
SomeExternalClass obj = GetSomeExternalObjectFromAnOldAPI();
SomeExternalProperty property = obj.SomeProperty;
DoStuff(property); // C# is confident that property is not null, here
```

Here is a screenshot of the condition:

[image: Failure 1]

Doing the following doesn't provide a null warning either. C# still confidently assumes the external API is perfectly non-nullable:

```
#nullable enable
SomeExternalClass obj = GetSomeExternalObjectFromAnOldAPI();
SomeExternalProperty? property = obj.SomeProperty;
DoStuff(property); // C# is still confident that property is not null, here
```

[image: Failure 2]

Is there a way that I can force C# to acknowledge that a variable may be null, even if it is supposedly confident it won't be? The opposite of the ! symbol. 'Trust me, this garbage can be null..'

RESOLVED. ACCEPTED ANSWER:

```
#nullable enable
SomeExternalClass obj = GetSomeExternalObjectFromAnOldAPI();
SomeExternalProperty? property = obj.SomeProperty ?? null;
DoStuff(property); // C# is now warning about possible null
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a non-nullable reference type in C# 8 be null in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531048/can-a-non-nullable-reference-type-in-c-sharp-8-be-null-in-runtime)

Comment: Nope, I would like a syntax mechanism for forcing C# to acknowledge a possible null so that I get warned about it when consuming the value. Saying 'remember to do null checks, guys' defeats the purposes of the whole C#8 thing.

Especially when VS explicitly tells me 'hey man, this will never be null' when it frequently is. False confidence and all that. Would be better off without the new features.

Comment: don't be blaming c# when the problem is the external library.  A library is supposed to report exceptions it can throw and return types.  That's all c# has to work with.  Note that you said in your question  "the external library is not produced with C#8/nullable types:" which specifically is saying it can NOT be null.

Comment: The ideal case would be that any external library not produced with the new C# syntax (I will frequently butcher the phrasing here, so trust we know what I am talking about) automatically attains ? at the end of every single function, method, return type, property, blah to reflect the fact that there are no guarantees from them. 

But I totally understand that this is probably not technically possible. I just wanted a mechanism to revoke the 'trust' C# was applying to the external library, which I now have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`ElementId? viewTemplateId = (revitView.ViewTemplateId ?? someNullTypeOfYourChoosing);`

Alternatively, allow the `View` and `revitView.ViewTemplateId` structs to be nullable/return nullable types.

Comment: ```SomeExternalProperty? property = obj.SomeProperty ?? null;```

succeeds in forcing C# to recognise a possible null. Cheers.

Comment: Interesting. So what happens in this case if the referenced library is recompiled with `#nullable enable` and now guarantees no nulls? Does the behavior change, or is this method "overfit" for this specific case?

Comment: Not sure! Would be worth a test. My guess would be that nothing would change in terms of errors or warnings - the calling code would just be adding unnecessary null checks that never get executed at runtime.

I know for a fact however that this particular API I'm referencing is not going to adopt ```#nullable enable``` anytime soon! They love returning nulls all over the shop in completely unexpected places.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method ‘void MaybeNull([System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.MaybeNull] T t)’ and use it.