# What is the difference between the `is` operator and a cast to a generic type?

Tags: c#, nullable

Why does the first function compile and the second emit a warning? Are the two implementations not equivalent? The type of `valT` is `T` in both implementations.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/XV5AXU

```cs
T To1<T>(object? val)
{
  if (!(val is T valT))
  {
    throw new InvalidCastException();
  }

  return valT;
}

T To2<T>(object? val)
{
  var valT = (T)val;

  return valT; // Possible null reference return
}
```

Comment: is returns false if value is null, while null can be casted to T (if T is reference type).

Comment: Try passing `null` to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**: You *probably* do not need to implement a generic "Cast" method. Be careful when implementing generic methods in C# for performance to avoid boxing (avoid using `object`). Additionally if you hide the actual explicit cast operator in a generic method then the C# compiler can't give the consuming code *early warning* that a cast is provably incorrect.

Consider:

```
Int32 i = new Int32();
String s = (String)o; // <-- CS0030 Cannot convert type 'int' to 'string'
```

But with your code:

```
Int32 i = new Int32();
String s1 = To1<String>( i ); // No compiler error, despite incompatible types.
String s2 = To2<String>( i ); // Also no compiler error.
```

---

As for your questions:

> Are the two implementations not equivalent?

No. See what happens when you pass `val: null`:

```
// Using your functions `To1` and `To2`:

String strFromObj  = To1<String>( new Object() ); // throws InvalidCastException (thrown from your code)
String strFromNull = To1<String>( null         ); // throws InvalidCastException (thrown from your code)

String strFromObj  = To2<String>( new Object() ); // throws InvalidCastException (thrown from the operator)
String strFromNull = To2<String>( null         ); // returns null;
```

> Why does the first function compile and the second emit a warning?

- Your first function uses the `is` operator, which is **safe** and will never throw (note that it is *your code* which is throwing `InvalidCastException` in this case).
- Your second function *blindly* uses a cast expression without doing a type-check first so it's unsafe because the operator itself throws `InvalidCastException` if `T` is incorrect, *unless* the operand is `null`.

---

1. The `foo is T bar` operator tests the type **of non-`null` values**. If `foo` is `null` then the `is` expression returns false and `bar` is `default(T)`.
2. The `T bar = (T)foo` cast expression **will cast `null` values** but only if `T` is a reference type - but this syntax may also invoke a custom explicit conversion operator instead of performing a cast.

---

Also note that C# 8.0's nullable-reference-types feature (`object?`) is not enforced at runtime: [the compiler does not add `throw new ArgumentNullException` statements to your compiled code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531048/can-a-non-nullable-reference-type-in-c-sharp-8-be-null-in-runtime), so if you change your code to use `object` instead of `object?` you should still add `if( val is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(val) );`.